# How to properly use socket.io in combination with Vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io, vue-cli

I am making a chat app with Vue.js, Node/Express, and socket.io. I create a socket instance in every component required and this results in numerous connections when a single page is loaded which is obviously unwanted behaviour. I then tried to create one instance of the socket object in my parent component and pass it to the children using props but it was unsuccessful. How can I get around this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How was it unsuccessful? If you need the connection in several places throughout your app, you might consider using Vuex to store the connection globally instead of passing it down to every child all the time. This heavily depends on the general structure of your app though.

Comment: It was unsuccessful in the sense that I was able to pass the socket.io object up from the parent component to the child but the libraries functions were not recognized...maybe a syntax error tbh...im a vue noob but either way thank you so much I just started using Vuex and it worked...Im kinda starting to feel like props are unncessary tbh....especially in big apps...no??? once again thanks for you help!

Comment: You want Vuex for global things but not everything. It would bloat your app over time. Props come when the component gets created and go when the component is destroyed thus using less memory in total. In vuex everything is available all the time. Just ask yourself: Do I need to access this data from multiple components all the time? If yes -> Vuex. If no -> props.